# OOP concept by destructors?

Tags: oop, destructor

Which Object Oriented Programming concept is displayed by destructors? For example, overloading shows polymorphism. Please explain the reason for your answer. I could not find this anywhere on the web..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the key OOP concepts are shown by destructors. If we consider those concepts as including *Inheritance*, *Object*, *Class*, *Encapsulation*, *Method*, *Message Passing*, *Polymorphism*, *Abstraction*, *Composition*, *Delegation* and *Open recursion*. Then we can show all of them being at play in destructors generally.

Now, generally "destructor" means a method that is defined in a class that is automatically invoked when an object is destroyed*. That obviously covers *method*, *object* and *class*.

Destructors encapsulate clean-up logic. Consider a structure that can point to another structure:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
   SomeStruct* Next;
}
```

If the above was written in a language that didn't support object-oriented design by letting us define a method on `SomeStruct` itself, and that deletes heap objects with a global `delete()` method, then to clean up **all** the memory used by a SomeStruct we'd need to do something like:

```
CleanUpSomeStruct(SomeStruct* toDelete)
{
  while(toDelete != null)
  {
    SomeStruct* deleteNext = someStruct->Next;
    delete(toDelete);
    toDelete = deleteNext;
  }
}
```

Notably:

1. We have to do the work to clean up `SomeStruct` outside of `SomeStruct`.
2. There's nothing to prevent this being duplicated elsewhere. Perhaps incorrectly.
3. We have to be able to access `Next` directly, increasing the number of places we might do something unwise with it.
4. If we have cases where we shouldn't delete `Next`, then while that knowledge could be stored in `SomeStruct` (perhaps an `ownsNext` field), the logic of acting on that knowledge is external to `SomeStruct`.

If we have destructors then:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
   SomeStruct* Next;
   ~SomeStruct()
   {
     if(Next != null) delete(Next);
   }
}
```

In contrast to the above:

1. The work to clean up `SomeStruct` is in `SomeStruct`, close to other `SomeStruct`-related code.
2. It's possible to have a concept of access-control, which can prevent this being duplicated elsewhere.
3. Likewise, access-control can stop other cases of accessing `Next` directly, decreasing the number of places we might do something unwise with it.
4. If we have cases where we shouldn't delete `Next`, then that logic can be stored in one place internal to `SomeStruct`.

On the flip side, since encapsulation means that we may not be able to access `Next` encapsulation means that we **have** to have destructors to be able to clean up objects (or give the method an explicit "Clean Yourself Up" method, but having to remember to call it every time, and know if it even exists in a given case, and what it's called is a drag). Obviously this example wouldn't matter if we had automatic garbage collection, but in those cases we would similarly need to have destructors of some sort if encapsulation blocked outside code from necessary clean-up task.

Likewise, if we have *inheritance*, we need to have inheritable destructors that can pass the clean-up task up the line either implicitly or explicitly:

```
struct SomeOtherStruct : SomeStruct
{
  SomeStruct* Prev;
  ~SomeOtherStruct()
  {
    if(Prev != null) delete(Prev);
    base.~SomeStruct(); // Possibly this would be implicit in that
                        // the language would automatically make a
                        // call to a destructor finish with a call
                        // to any base destructors.
  }
}
```

This also requires that destructors be *abstract* in the general sense of being part of the abstract model of what an object is (it may not have anything to do with an `abstract` keyword used to enforce abstraction in other contexts). They must be *polymorphic* so that `delete(Prev)` calls the most derived destructor in the object pointed to by `Prev` whether it is `~SomeStruct()`, `~SomeOtherStruct()` or the destructor of yet another derived type, so *Message Passing/Dynamic Dispatch* is used to find the correct implementation of the abstract/virtual destructor. (A language may enforce this, or may allow non-virtual destructors as an optimisation).

Finally destructors interact with encapsulation and open recursion in that they will have to (perhaps implicitly) call the destructors of objects they are composed of, and perhaps call into methods on themselves to do this.

*"when an object is destroyed" is a plainer concept for languages/frameworks using deterministic deletion of objects than those with non-deterministic garbage collection. Generally in the later case "destructor" refers to a method that runs when that non-deterministic collection finally happens (assuming it ever does) but if they have a separate "disposal" method that can be deterministic then it may serve some of the rôles that deterministic destructors serve. In particular while deterministic destructors can be useful in providing for the RAII technique, non-deterministic destructors do not and any use of RAII-like approaches would have to be part of a deterministic disposal.

Answer (score 1):

The practice of freeing up your program resources exists before OOP came to life. Even in old school C, without any objects, you have to free your memory accordingly or you get memory leaks, resource locks or other not nice consequences.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is Garbage Collection. In oop you can relate it with freeing up space that was previously allocated to any object which is no longer needed or deleted.

To quote the wikipedia

> In object-oriented programming, a destructor (sometimes shortened to
>   dtor) is a method which is automatically invoked when the object is
>   destroyed.

It's role is useful in cleanup, as in freeing up memory space that is longer used by your program anymore. Since most of the modern programming langauge has automatic Garbage Collection, the explicit call to the destructor is no longer needed.

Read about [GC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) and [Finalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer) for more info.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors implement what we know as "[Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)"

Comment: If the destruction is deterministic then it **can** be used to implement RAII (though if anything it should be called Resource Release Is Destruction).